# Conditional Hiding of WinRT/XAML Controls Using Style - Possible?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, hide

In my WinRT/Phone 8.1 app I have a form with a number of `Grid`s (serving as wrappers) each containing two or more `TextBlock`s. I want to show only data that is available, meaning that if the content `TextBlock` of a particular `Grid` is empty I want to hide the entire `Grid`.

For instance:´

```
<Grid x:Name="NameSection">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               x:Name="NameLabel"
               Text="Name:" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               x:Name="Name"
               Text="{Binding Name}" />
</Grid>
```

If the *Name* `TextBlock` is empty, the entire `Grid`'s visibility should be collapsed.

Adding logic for this either to code behind or (worse) the `ViewModel` could get messy for this long form, so I wonder if I can achieve this using XAML and styles. How can it be done in WinRT? Can I style the `Grid` such that it's visibility is based on the content in one of its subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converter

```cs
public class NullToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value == null ? Visibility.Collapsed: Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

then use it like this

```
<Grid x:Name="NameSection" Visibility={Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource MyNullConverter}}>
```

edit:
you can add string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) insted of value == null, if you want to check empty strings as well